# Dynamically adding a row in data table Kivy/KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

For example I have an empty data table (with only column data) and a button. I want to dynamically add row data when button is pressed. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. The widget `MDDataTable` doesn't permit natively the addition of data dynamically to the table, as is discussed [here](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/483).
Nonetheless, one can easily circumvent that by creating a new the table with the new data and show it. It can become process heavy, but for smaller tables it works just fine.

I made an example using kivy 2.0.0 and kivymd 0.104.1:

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.i = 0
        self.rowData = ["Row. No."]
        self.button = Button(text="AddRow", size_hint_y=None, pos_hint={"bottom": 0})
        self.button.bind(texture_size=self.button.setter('size'))
        self.data_tables = None
        self.set_table(self.rowData)

    def set_table(self, data):
        if self.data_tables:
            self.data_tables.ids.container.remove_widget(self.button)

        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(size_hint=(0.9, 0.6), use_pagination=True, check=True,
                                       column_data=[("No.", dp(30))], row_data=[self.rowData])

        self.data_tables.ids.container.add_widget(self.button)

    def on_start(self):
        self.data_tables.open()
        self.button.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.addrow())

    def addrow(self):
        self.data_tables.dismiss(animation=False)
        self.i += 1
        self.set_table(self.rowData.append("Row {}".format(self.i)))
        self.data_tables.open(animation=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

Note: While running this code i ran into an error:

```
ValueError: TableRecycleGridLayout.orientation is set to an invalid option 'vertical'. Must be one of: ['lr-tb', 'tb-lr', 'rl-tb', 'tb-rl', 'lr-bt', 'bt-lr', 'rl-bt', 'bt-rl']
```

It's a known issue of incompatibility. To solve it, all there is needed is to follow the instructions in this [here](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/596#issuecomment-714913584)

Answer (score 0):

AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31633780)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can dynamically add rows, just add a row to the row_data array.
To dynamically update the item index, simply find out the length of the array len(self.data_table.row_data), and this will be our last item and simply add +1

```
def add_row(self):      
     self.data_table.row_data.append([str(len(self.data_table.row_data)+1),
                                    "2","3","4"])
```